# Buoyancy in the hydrostatic equation

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-statics, buoyancy

I have a question regarding the fundamental equation of hydrostatic, namely:
$\vec\nabla P=\rho \vec g$.

Why do we not take into account in Newton's 2nd law (used to prove this equation) the buoyancy? Is it because the local force of pressure ($\vec \nabla P$) is equivalent to the buoyancy? If so, why?

Why do we not take into account either the gravitational force of the fluid on itself (I mean, when we apply Newton's 2nd law to a particle of fluid, the said particle is subject to the gravitational force created by the rest of the fluid)?

Thank you very much,

Respectfully,

AF

Comment: Buoyancy is a force on a submerged object whose average density is different from the fluid's density. How would you take into account buoyancy for the fluid itself? (Which has the same density as the fluid... :) )

Answer (score 0):

> Is it because the local force of pressure (∇⃗ P) is equivalent to the
> buoyancy?

Yes. The pressure from below is greater than on the top of a submerged object. If it will float or not, it depends on its weight, compared with the force resultant from this pressure gradient.